# Skype conference with two people in the room

Tags: skype, microphone, conferencing

How to organize skype conference with two people in the room and avoid two microphones input overlay? Each user must have his own headphone to hear audio from his own PC. Should I buy specific headsets with directional microphones?

Comment: Buy one microphone for all of them.

Comment: We sit with 4 guys behind one webcam and microphone, works like a charm :)... Those meetings are never longer than 30 minutes though.

Comment: @gronostaj It will not help. If you use one microphone for UserA and UserB, one of them will hear his own voice in conference.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid As I said "each user must have his own headphone to hear audio from his own PC"

Comment: @Vell use one microphone, one PC and a headphone splitter. Or just use TeamSpeak instead of Skype, it allows selective muting.

Comment: @gronostaj I can't use one PC - each user must hear his own audio from his own PC. Thank you for TeamSpeak suggestion, but I hope someone help me find solution with skype due higher popularity of it.